# Change properties of a class from time to time

Tags: javascript

I have two functions. In the first one I increase a variable by adding 100 to it and I put a setInterval so the funcion repeats itself after some time. The other function is a class, a contrusctor to create an object. I want this.x_origen to get increased by adding aumento to it after some time and repeat it. However what I'm getting here is that the first function increases aument and then it finishes and then the second function starts. How can I solve this?

```
var aument = 0;
function aumento(){ 
    aument = aument + 100;
    return aument;
}
setInterval(function () {aumento()}, 1000/50);
function create_class_brick (x_origen_in, y_origen_in, x_final_in, y_final_in, mi_estado, mi_velocidad, mi_id){

    this.x_origen = x_origen_in + aumento();
    this.y_origen = y_origen_in;
    this.x_final = x_final_in + aumento();
    this.y_final = y_final_in;         
    this.estado = mi_estado;
    this.velocidad = mi_velocidad;
    this.id_elemento = mi_id;

    this.DESPLAZAR_LADRILLO  = desplazar_ladrillo;
    this.F0 = f0;
    this.F2 = f2;

    this.crear_ladrillo = crear_ladrillo;
    this.obtener_x_origen_ladrillo = obtener_x_origen_ladrillo;
    this.obtener_y_origen_ladrillo = obtener_y_origen_ladrillo;
    this.obtener_x_final_ladrillo = obtener_x_final_ladrillo;
    this.obtener_y_final_ladrillo = obtener_y_final_ladrillo;
}
```

Comment: Is the desired result to have `this.x_origen` periodically updated with the current value of `aument`? Or is it to have `this.x_origen` update whenever `aument` updates?

Comment: @Jason Cust As the aument increases I want the this.x_origen to increase too. So it would be the second result you mentioned.

Comment: That is what a new proposal for Javascript called [`Object.observe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) will allow you to do. Unfortunately it is not implemented by default on most browsers yet so it will not be consistently available to use. That said, you could use a polyfill or use an internal polling solution. I would be concerned with performance though depending on how many objects are to be created.

Comment: @Jason Cust I created two objects so I think performance should go well. But how can I use a polyfill or an internal polling solution? I'm new to Javascript so I don't know about that.

Comment: Actually an alternative is to not technically store a value but to define a getter that will dynamically generate the correct value when requested. Please see my answer for an example.

Comment: have you checked the suggested answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

An example on how to wait for the initial call:

```
function brick (x_origen_in){
    this.x_origen = x_origen_in;
}

function aumento(brick){
    console.log(brick.x_origen);
    brick.x_origen += 100;
    setTimeout(aumento.bind(this, brick), 500);
}

var brick = new brick(100);
aumento(brick);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x6c08u39/

Comment: But doesn't give me the result I'm looking for. I want the this.x_origen to increase as the aument does.

Comment: @nmn I think you can figure out what to change in order to achieve that

Comment: should I change the setTimeout to a setInterval? I'm sorry if I don't understand it, I'm relatively new to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to dynamically generate the value whenever it is accessed.

First, lets simplify the auto-incrementing of `aument`:

```
var aument = 0;
function aumento(){ 
  aument += 100;
}

// The first argument for setInterval is the function to execute
// No need to figure out the interval value at runtime as there are no dynamic values
setInterval(aumento, 20); // 1000/50 === 20
```

Now lets make an object that will have a the correct value:

```
function create_class_brick (x_origen_in, y_origen_in, x_final_in, y_final_in, mi_estado, mi_velocidad, mi_id){
  Object.defineProperty(this, 'x_origen', {
    get: function () { return x_origen_in + aument; }
  });
  // Other stuff
  // ...  
}
```

A quick test:

```
> aument
34100
> var obj = new create_class_brick(23);
undefined
> obj.x_origen
161523
> obj.x_origen
167223
> obj.x_origen
172423
```